# How can I output an entire node of a json document in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I'm trying to use freemarker to extract parts of a JSON document and output them into a new document.  I keep running into the issue where freemarker complains:

> SEVERE: Error executing FreeMarker template
>   FreeMarker template error:
>   For "${...}" content: Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), but this has evaluated to an extended_hash (wrapper: f.c.HashLiteral$SequenceHash):
>   ==> m.name  [in template "testjson.ftl" at line 8, column 15]

My template works fine when the element m.name evaluates to a string, but I want to use it to extract an entire node.  The template is:

```
<#assign m = doc?eval>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test JSON</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>${m.name}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine with a simple structure:

```
{
    "name" : "joe",
    "number": "123-456-7890"
}
```

But not a complex one:

```
{
    "name" : 
        {   
            "first" : "joe",
            "last" : "developer"
        },
    "number":"123-456-7890"
}
```

Is it possible to easily extract and output an entire node?

Thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, currently (2.3.23) there's no JSON support in FTL out of the box (apart from JSON escaping). Of course, one could write a "toJSON" `TemplateMethodModelEx` that does this.